# Elliptical orbits from Newtonian Euler-Lagrange equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, lagrangian-formalism, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion

For an exercise in general relativity, I needed to derive the equation of motion for a planet (mass $m=1, G=1$) orbiting a stationary star (mass $M>>1$), in Newtonian physics and general relativity. I could do this in general relativity, but not Newtonian physics.

The relativistic result (from the geodesic equation in Schwarzschild metric) is:

$$u''(\phi)+u(\phi)=\frac{M}{J^2}+3Mu^2.$$

But trying to get the Newtonian result from the Euler-Lagrange equation gives me the following error:

$$u''+u=2\frac{(u')^2}{u^1}+\frac{M}{J^2}.$$

In the above $J$ is angular momentum and $u(\phi)=1/r$ is the inverse distance to the star as a function of angle since perihelion, and $$u''=\partial^2 u/\partial t^2.$$

In that exercise, approximating the Newtonian result from the relativistic answer was an acceptable solution, but I want to know why my Newtonian derivation fails:

My faulty derivation is as follows

In Newtonian physics, in radial coordinates $(r,\phi)$ the Lagrangian is:

$$\mathcal{L}=\frac{1}{2}(\dot{r}^2+r^2\dot{\phi}^2)+\frac{M}{r}.$$

The Euler-Lagrange equation for $\phi$ trivially gives $r^2\dot{\phi}=J$ where $J$ is a constant (angular momentum), this was also in the relativistic version so I think that is correct. The $r$ equation gives me:

$$\frac{d}{dt}\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial \dot{r}}=\frac{\partial\mathcal{L}}{\partial r}.$$

So

$$\ddot{r}=r\dot{\phi}^2-\frac{M}{r^2}=\frac{J^2}{r^3}-\frac{M}{r^2}.$$

Though this is most certainly wrong, numerous derivations have failed to produce different results.

Now, to write it in terms of $u(\phi)$ I use the chain rule: $$\ddot{r}=\partial^2 r/\partial t^2=\partial^2 r/\partial \phi^2\partial^2 \phi/\partial t^2=r''/\ddot{\phi}=r''J^2/r^4$$ (This is valid here since  $\ddot{\phi}=0$). I do not believe that is wrong , since that worked fine in the relativistic derivation.

So I think:

$$r''=r-\frac{r^2M}{J^2}.$$

Now, I need to write this as $u''$ instead, and I believe that

$$r''=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \phi^2} \left(\frac{1}{u}\right)= \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi} \left(-\frac{u'}{u^2}\right) =2\frac{(u')^2}{u^3}-\frac{u''}{u^2}. $$

Now, putting this back, substituting $1/r\rightarrow u$ and factoring out $1/u^2$ gives me the following false result

$$2\frac{(u')^2}{u}-u''=u-\frac{M}{J^2}.$$

So

$$2\frac{(u')^2}{u}+\frac{M}{J^2}=u''+u.$$

This is absurd, there is an additional term involving the single derivative of $u(\phi)$, which does not appear in the relativistic expression and can not be argued to be 0.

Yet, I fail to see where the above derivations went wrong.

Comment: $\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dr}{d\phi}\frac{d\phi}{dt}$ and $\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}=\frac{d^2 r}{d\phi^2}\left(\frac{d\phi}{dt}\right)^2+\frac{dr}{d\phi}\frac{d^2 \phi}{dt^2}$, so what you don't believe is wrong is already wrong.  I didn't check the rest.  Also, why do you think that $\frac{d^2 \phi}{dt^2}$ is zero?  I'm pretty sure the dependence of $\phi$ on $t$ in Kepler orbit is a horrendously complicated function, though I once tried and Wolfram Alpha was able to solve for it :)

Comment: Correction, the Wolfram Alpha solution was for $t$ as a function $\phi$, which is horrendously complicated.  There is no way $\frac{d^2 \phi}{dt^2}$ is zero.  It's the angular momentum that's constant, but $r$ is not constant except in circular motion which the ground state of lowest energy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from
$$\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}=\frac{J^2}{r^3}-\frac{M}{r^2}\tag{1}$$
and $u=1/r$
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{du}{d\phi} &= \frac{du}{dr}\frac{dr}{d\phi} = -\frac{1}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\phi}\\
\frac{dr}{dt}=\frac{dr}{d\phi}\frac{d\phi}{dt}&=\frac{J}{r^2}\frac{dr}{d\phi}=-J\frac{du}{d\phi}\\
\frac{d^2 r}{dt^2}=-J\frac{d^2 u}{d\phi^2}\frac{d\phi}{dt}&=-\frac{J^2}{r^2}\frac{d^2 u}{d\phi^2}=-J^2 u^2\frac{d^2 u}{d\phi^2}
\end{align}
$$
Substituting into $(1)$ gives
$$
-J^2 u^2\frac{d^2 u}{d\phi^2}=J^2u^3-Mu^2
$$
Divide this by $-J^2 u^2$ and I'll let you do the rest.